# Disabling JS Server from running on react-native run-android command

Tags: react-native, windows-7

- I perform offline bundling of my react-native project using CMD

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/`

- As bundinling is done offline i dont want JS server to start each time after running the command `react-native run-android`.

Is there any way out to avoid starting JS server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, `react-native run-android` starts the packager and run installDebug task on gradlew.

To just run installDebug, on your project root directory run:

```
cd android && ./gradlew installDebug
```

Comment: in windows 7 its give error `'.' is not recognised as internal or external command`. So i ran it as `cd android` and then `gradlew installdebug` but now the app is only installed and doesn't launches automatically on the device. I need to launch app manually after being installed. Is there any other way around for this

Comment: Yeah, the './' is for unix-like systems.
Asking your question, you can start any debug app via adb:
`adb -s <device id> shell am start -n <com.app.package.id>/.MainActivity`